# Try Catch and Negative Inputs

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have an InputMismatchException which stops a decimal from being entered, but it doesn't help for negative integers/negative decimals.

```
if(userInput == 1) {

            int l;

            l = 0;

            try {

                l = input.nextInt();


            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                System.out.println("");
                input.next();

            } 

        }
```

If I add a do while loop with an if statement for anything equal to or less than zero it will loop within the if(userInput == 1) statement instead of starting from the beginning of the menu like it does if a positive decimal is entered. It also doesn't help for negative decimals.

I've tried to add two exceptions to the catch, but can't get that to work.

Comment: *it will loop within the if(userInput == 1) statement* an `if` is **not** a `loop`

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604342/im-trying-to-add-a-try-catch-that-tells-the-user-they-cant-plug-in-negative-numb

Comment: There could still be content in the buffer, either that or `userInput` needs to be reset, but since you've not graced us with a working example of your problem, it's impossible to know what to suggest

Comment: see this possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950713/scanner-input-validation-in-while-loop and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19130231/2310289)

Comment: one of the set of possible solutions: add method readInt throws InputMismatchException to your code, inside do `l = input.nextInt();` and then validate it's > 0 and throw InputMismatchException if it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just turn your int into a String and check if it has a decimal point or a negative sign.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int l;
    while (true)
    {
        l = input.nextInt();
        if ((""+l).indexOf('.') >= 0 || (""+l).indexOf('-') >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println(/*your message here*/);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

//continue with your program
```

Edit: Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (input < 0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input cannot be negative.");
}
```

If the number is negative, it will throw the exception and then the catch code can be executed.

Comment: When I add that to the try statement it doesn't execute the catch code. Here is what I've put. `try {
                    
                    l = input.nextInt();
                    
                    if (l < 0){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input cannot be negative.");
                }`

Comment: @anyset - Obviously!  What you need to do is understand this suggestion, and adapt it to your context.  If you are going to throw an exception, throw an exception **that you catch**.  But, frankly, throwing an exception is not the right solution ... given the way that you are currently handling the other exception.  The key is to try to understand what exceptions / exception handling offer, and use them (or not!) appropriately.  (Hammers are not good screwdrivers)

Comment: I agree! - instead of throwing an exception you could is simply refuse any negative input

Comment: This all makes sense. Now it refuses negative input. Thank you.