# Checking for user only input positive value

Tags: java

I'm preventing the user from inputting string, but I want to check whether user input zero or negative number too. How should I do it in the same do-while loop?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Check{
public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int a = 0;
     boolean invalidInput;
      do {
            invalidInput = false;
            try {
                System.out.println("\nEnter the positive integer");
                a = input.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid positive integer.\n");  
                invalidInput = true;
                input.nextLine();
            } 
        } while (invalidInput);
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Im trying to add a try catch that tells the user they cant plug in negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604342/im-trying-to-add-a-try-catch-that-tells-the-user-they-cant-plug-in-negative-numb)

Comment: look into conditional statements. entering negative will not (should not) throw exceptions.

Comment: u mean   while (invalidInput && a > 0) something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
 do {
            invalidInput = false;
            try {
                System.out.println("\nEnter the positive integer");
                String num = input.next();
                int a = Integer.parseInt(num); // <-- this will throw NumberformatException if user inputs Alphabets
                if(a <= 0) { //<-- added 
                    throw new NumberFormatException();
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid positive integer.\n");  
                invalidInput = true;
                input.nextLine();
            } 
        } while (invalidInput);
```

Output:

```
Enter the positive integer
0
Please enter a valid positive integer.

Enter the positive integer
-1
Please enter a valid positive integer.
```

Comment: thank you, but I think using this loop will fail to test string input

Comment: Yes it will. if u wanna test String too. Try this `String num = input.next()` and then in do while do `int a = Integer.parseInt(num)`  and then remaining code will work.  Have edited the post! Do check. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0;
        boolean invalidInput;
        do {
            invalidInput = false;
            try {
                System.out.println("\nEnter the positive integer");
                a = input.nextInt();
                if(a<0){
                    throw new Exception("Negative number entered");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("It is a positive integer. Exiting.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid positive integer.\n");  
                invalidInput = true;
                input.nextLine();
            } 
        } while (invalidInput);

    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Enter the positive integer                                                                                                                                  
10                                                                                                                                                          
It is a positive integer. Exiting.
```

**Another run for negative check:**

```
Enter the positive integer                                                                                                                                  
-10                                                                                                                                                         
Please enter a valid positive integer.                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            
Enter the positive integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific class to ask that user input, with the necessary logic to filter invalid answers.

Something like:

```java
class Console {

    private Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    private String readLine() {
        if (!reader.hasNextLine()) return ""; // Control exit here
        return reader.nextLine();
    }

    public int answerInt(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);

        String provided = readLine();
        if (isInteger(provided)) return Integer.parseInt(provided);

        System.err.println("You have entered an invalid value. Please provide a number.");
        return answerInt(message);
    }

    private boolean isInteger(String string) { // This should be a number util, not a console class responsability.
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(string);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception er) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Then, for example, just add a new method to handle the allowed number range.

```java
public int answerNumberBetween(int min, int max, String message) {
    int num = answerInt(message);

    // Validate if the number is between the provided range.
    if (num >= min && num <= max) return num;

    System.err.println("You have entered an invalid value. Please provide a number between '%d' and '%d'.", min, max);
    return answerNumberBetween(min, max, message);
}
```